# How can I force Spring SAML to reread my IDP metadata?

Tags: spring, saml, spring-saml

I've implemented a spring saml metadata provider that reads from a database and serves up both my service providers and identity providers.  I'm also leveraging aliases to act as tenant identifiers.

My problem is if I go into the database and modify the metadata for a particular identity provider to be different, it doesn't seem to have any effect until I restart the spring saml extension.  This is independent of whether I wait for the MetadataManager reload thread to kick off.

What's being cached here?  Can I prevent this behavior?

It looks like something is being cached in the SAML message validation code.  If I start up the process with invalid metadata, then correct the metadata, I will no matter what get Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid.

Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit:*  I believe I found the location where this is happening:  In MetadataCredentialResolver.java, the credentials are cached via a call to cacheCredentials after it retrieves it from the metadata provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by overriding MetadataCredentialResolver and making cacheCredentials a no-op.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, It would be great if you can exactly specify what you did