# Spring SAML: updating Metadata Provider does not update signing certificates used

Tags: java, spring, spring-saml

I've recently implemented a Spring SAML solution which allows customers to register their IdP Metadata with a service and use their SAML authentication to access my SP.

The IdP Metadata is stored as a Database entry as part of a custom AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider implementation, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906985/spring-saml-reading-and-refreshing-idp-metadata-at-runtime)  :

---

```java
public class DbIdpMetadataProvider extends AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider {
...
  @Override
  protected byte[] fetchMetadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
  IdpProviderData provider  = null; // DAO of IdP metadata in DB

  try {

    log.info("Attempting to retrieve DB provider data for entity: " + entityId);

    provider = dbService.getIdpByEntityId(entityId);

    // verify that we have a provider
    if ( null != provider) {

      // get last update time recorded in DB
      DateTime lastUpdate = getLastUpdate();

      log.info("Performing refresh of Metadata Provider XML by reading from database");


      String metadataBody = provider.getMetadataBody();
      emitChangeEvent();
      return metadataBody.getBytes();
    }


    // if no provider, throw an exception as this metadata provider instance is invalid
    else {
      log.error("IdP Provider could not be found for EntityId: " + entityId );
      throw new MetadataProviderException("Metadata could not be found for String entity: " + entityId);
    }

  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Failed to query database for provider entity: " + entityId);
    throw new MetadataProviderException("Failed to query database for provider entity: " + entityId, e);
  }

}
```

---

When the metadata is updated, I save the metadata XML to the database and remove the previous instance of the Metadata Provider from the CachingMetadataManager. I then import the Certificates from the metadata to a local keystore and add a new metadata provider instance to the CachingMetadataManager:

```java
@Autowired
private MetadataManager       metadataManager;

...

/**
 * Update our existing IdP metadata provider with new XML and other information
 */
public void updateIdpMetadata(IdPRegistrationData _data) throws RequiredDataException, NotFoundException, SystemException {
  IdpProviderData           provider;
  XMLObject                 xml;
  String                    metadataXml;
  EntityDescriptor          entity;
  String                    entityId;

  try {
    
    // validation
    validateIdpRegistrationData(_data);

    //ensure our top level DOM element is the IDPSSO entity descriptor, removing all other metadata
    xml         = parseMetadataXml(_data.getMetadataXml());
    entity      = getIDPSSOParentEntityDescriptor(xml);
    entityId    = entity.getEntityID();
    metadataXml = serialize(entity);
    
    // get our provider Data
    provider    = getIdpByAccountSysid(_data.getAccountSysid());
    
    if ( null == provider) {
      throw new NotFoundException(NotFoundExceptionType.ACCOUNT);
    }
    
    // update our provider
    provider.setEntityId(entityId);
    provider.setMetadataBody(metadataXml);
    
    // save data in database
    metadataStoreDao.saveAndFlush(provider);
    keystoreMgr.importMetadataCertificates(xml, provider.getUrlContext());
    
    // remove existing provider from metadata store
    removeDelegateFromManager(entityId);
    
    // reintroduce delegate to manager
    loadIdpMetadata(provider);
         
  }
  catch(NotFoundException e) {
    log.error("No previous version of IDP registration metadata found to update.",e);
    throw (e);
  }
  catch (MetadataProviderException e){
    log.error("Failed to update Keystore and Signing algorithm of IdP Metadata.",e);
    throw new SystemException("Failed to update certificates.");
  }
  catch(RequiredDataException e) {
    log.error("Missing required data for update.",e);
    throw(e);
  }

}

/**
 * Remove the metadata provider from our manager
 */
private void removeDelegateFromManager( String _entityId ) throws MetadataProviderException {
  ExtendedMetadataDelegate  delegate;
  DbIdpMetadataProvider     provider;
  
  delegate  = findMetadataDelegate(_entityId);
  
  if( null == delegate){
    log.error("Failed to find Delegate in metadata manager for Entity ID: " + _entityId );
    return;
  }
  
  metadataManager.removeMetadataProvider(delegate);
  provider = (DbIdpMetadataProvider)delegate.getDelegate();
  provider.destroy();
  metadataManager.setRefreshRequired(true);
  metadataManager.refreshMetadata();

}    

/**
 * load our provider data to a metadata provider object
 */
private void loadIdpMetadata(IdpProviderData _providerData) throws MetadataProviderException {
  DbIdpMetadataProvider idpProvider;

  // initialize our IdP provider
  idpProvider     = new DbIdpMetadataProvider(_providerData);
  idpProvider.setParserPool(parser);
  addIdpToMetadataManager(idpProvider);

}

/**
 * Add the metadata provider to our cache
 */
private void addIdpToMetadataManager(DbIdpMetadataProvider _provider) throws MetadataProviderException {
  ExtendedMetadataDelegate  delegate;
  ExtendedMetadata          extMeta = new ExtendedMetadata();
  
  // initialize our provider
  _provider.initialize();
  
  extMeta     = createExtendedMetadata(_provider);

  delegate    = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(_provider, extMeta);
  delegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
  delegate.initialize();
  
  metadataManager.addMetadataProvider(delegate);
  metadataManager.setRefreshRequired(true);
  metadataManager.refreshMetadata();
}
```

The problem is that when a database entry is refreshed, the new signing certificate defined in the <ds:X509Certificate> element in the IdP metadata is not applied.

I can see the new certificate when I print out the Metadata XML:

---

```xml
<!--  new signing key  -->
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIC4jCCAcqgAwIBAgIQafZAY7...</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIC3DCCAcSgAwIBAgIQeny6jM...</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIC3DCCAcSgAwIBAgIQRtno3W...</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
```

---

I receive a SUCCESS SAML response from my IdP at time of SP initiated sign on:

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="https://{my-domain}:443/eas-saml/saml/SSO" ID="_0d023fb8-bf24-4b78-b690-c9b53df4db72" InResponseTo="a22h6bb0gf2e8f314e00316b198ddg1" IssueInstant="2018-10-17T18:31:47.332Z" Version="2.0">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://{my-domain}/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
   </samlp:Status>
   <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_317d062d-247e-4405-9dd8-0ef3d032bf3f" IssueInstant="2018-10-17T18:31:47.332Z" Version="2.0">
      <Issuer>http://{my-domain}/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_8049000b-6e76-416c-84aa-180d61ca359a">
               <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               </ds:Transforms>
               <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
               <ds:DigestValue>x/PKyqXDECmE2IBNiZ0pqet3HqQYgDwlbeo1Vb3gXD8=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
         </ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:SignatureValue>UvhpsDE7XT1uvqGbA+IZ2sC9t8x0i42/P7tdNXO...</ds:SignatureValue>
         <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC3DCCAcSgAwIBAgIQRtno3W...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <Subject>
         <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">userId</NameID>
         <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a22h6bb0gf2e8f314e00316b198ddg1" NotOnOrAfter="2018-10-17T18:36:47.332Z" Recipient="https://{my-domain}:443/eas-saml/saml/SSO"/>
         </SubjectConfirmation>
      </Subject>
      <Conditions NotBefore="2018-10-17T18:31:47.327Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-10-17T18:33:47.327Z">
         <AudienceRestriction>
            <Audience>https://{my-domain}/eas-saml</Audience>
         </AudienceRestriction>
      </Conditions>
      <AttributeStatement>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
            <AttributeValue>userId</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://E-Mail-Addresses">
            <AttributeValue>user@domain.com</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
      </AttributeStatement>
      <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-10-17T18:31:47.233Z" SessionIndex="_317d062d-247e-4405-9dd8-0ef3d032bf3f">
         <AuthnContext>
            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>
         </AuthnContext>
      </AuthnStatement>
   </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>

----------

Where as the log output shows a failure with the following stack trace:

----------
<pre>
    2018-10-17 18:31:47 INFO  SAMLDefaultLogger:129 - AuthNResponse;FAILURE;172.17.0.1;https://{my-domain}/eas-saml;http://{my-domain}/adfs/services/trust;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
      at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
      at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
      at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
      at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:92)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
      at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    Caused by: org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature is not trusted or invalid
      at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:272)
      at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
      at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
      at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
      ... 39 more
</pre>
----------

If I restart the service, the signature is recognized and the response is successfully processed.

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong? Shouldn't a refresh of the metadata manager be enough to allow the new certificates be used? Or is there a step I'm missing?
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081242/how-can-i-force-spring-saml-to-reread-my-idp-metadata)

As I am currently using an XML config file, I modified the security context XML to set the Credential Resolver as follows:

```
<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl">
  <property name="metadataResolver">
            <bean class="com.mydomain.CustomMetadataCredentialResolver">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadata" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" ref="keyManager" />
                <property name="useXmlMetadata" value="true" />
            </bean>
  </property> 
</bean>
```

I then created a class that extends `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver`

For now, I simply override the cacheCredentials method:

```
@Component
public class CustomMetadataCredentialResolver extends MetadataCredentialResolver {

  public CustomMetadataCredentialResolver(MetadataManager metadataProvider, KeyManager keyManager) {
    super(metadataProvider, keyManager);
  }

  @Override
  protected void cacheCredentials( MetadataCacheKey cacheKey, Collection<Credential> credentials ) {
    //no-op
  }
}
```

I'll likely clean this up to clear the cache on command rather than never caching the credentials, but for now it works.